# Unable to install Visual Studio Express for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 on Windows 8 Pro 32-bit. The following error comes:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8
Cannot find the requested object.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: where/when are you getting this message?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your download may be corrupted.  You could try re-downloading it.